# Using CSS counter-reset in :host declaration of a Custom Element

Tags: css, custom-element, css-counter

[run the code snippet]

I want my DIV number display to start at **0** ,
so I want to start the counter at -1 using: `counter-reset : square -1;`

Yet, this setting is ignored when used in `:host`

`counter-reset` works fine when all DIVs are wrapped in an extra parentDIV 
 (with `counter-reset` on that parent DIV)
But I prefer **not** to use this *work-around* as it requires lots more code in my final application.

**Is it possible at all to use `counter-reset` in `:host` ???**

```js
window.customElements.define('game-toes', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
     .appendChild(document.querySelector('#Styles').content.cloneNode(true));
  }
});
```

```html
<TEMPLATE id="Styles">
  <STYLE>
      :host {
        display: grid;
        grid-template: repeat(3, 1fr) / repeat(3, 1fr);
        grid-gap: .5em;
        counter-reset: squarenr -1; /* does not reset to -1 */
      }
      DIV {
        font-size:3em;
        display:flex;
        justify-content:center;
        background:lightgrey;
        counter-increment: squarenr;
      }
      #_::before {
        background:lightgreen;
        content: counter(squarenr);
      }
      #X::after,
      #O::after {
        content: attr(id);
      }
  </STYLE>
  <DIV id=_></DIV><DIV id=_></DIV><DIV id=X></DIV>
  <DIV id=_></DIV><DIV id=X></DIV><DIV id=_></DIV>
  <DIV id=O></DIV><DIV id=O></DIV><DIV id=X></DIV>
</TEMPLATE>
<game-toes></game-toes>
```

---

[qomponents](http://qomponents.nl)

Comment: I'm not so sure why it does not work. But if you can wrap your content in another element, and have the counter reset there, then it works. It works on both resetting it on the container and the first element: http://jsfiddle.net/szmfj5kw/2/

Comment: Yes, I stated *'when wrapped in a parent DIV it works'* Thing is, I have more (observed) data-attributes on my Custom Element, also referenced in CSS. So the 'wrap-in-another-element' *work-around*  then requires lots more code to **duplicate** all those data-attributes on the container element. Therefor my question: Can counter-reset work in :host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:host` is a pseudo-class that selects the shadow host element (that is: the HTML element that hosts the Shadow DOM), not the shadow root.

As a consequence, a `counter-reset` will affect the counter in the main DOM tree, not the counter in the Shadow DOM (see the example below).

If you want to set a CSS counter in the Shadow DOM root, you could use the `:first-of-type` selector:

```
 div:first-of-type {
    counter-reset: squarenr -1
 }
```

```js
window.customElements.define('game-toes', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({mode: 'closed'})
     .appendChild(document.querySelector('#Styles').content.cloneNode(true));
  }
});
```

```css
div::after {
  counter-increment: squarenr ;
  content: counter( squarenr ) ;
}
```

```html
<TEMPLATE id="Styles">
  <STYLE>
      :host {
        display: grid;
        grid-template: repeat(3, 1fr) / repeat(3, 1fr);
        grid-gap: .5em;
        counter-reset: squarenr -1; 
      }
      :host > div:first-of-type {
        counter-reset: squarenr -1; 
        color: red;
      }
      DIV {
        font-size:2em;
        display:flex;
        justify-content:center;
        background:lightgrey;
        counter-increment: squarenr  ;
      }
      #_::before {
        background:lightgreen;
        content: counter(squarenr);
      }
      #X::after,
      #O::after {
        content: attr(id);
      }
  </STYLE>
  <DIV id=_></DIV><DIV id=_></DIV><DIV id=X></DIV>
  <DIV id=_></DIV><DIV id=X></DIV><DIV id=_></DIV>
  <DIV id=O></DIV><DIV id=O></DIV><DIV id=X></DIV>
</TEMPLATE>
<div>squarenr=</div><game-toes></game-toes><div>squarenr=</div>
```

Comment: spot on as ever. Raises the question: We can set a counter **in** the host, is there a way to increment that counter? (just wondering, don't need it for this app)

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman If I understand your question: yes you can increment the counter in :host inside main CSS stylesheet (as standard HTML element). See the edit code snippet.

Comment: I should have said: is there a way to increment that counter (in the host) FROM the Custom Element

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman maybe by adding dummy elements in the light DOM (which will be hidden by the Shadow DOM), or by resetting the CSS counter via Javascript code...